# Tomcat configuration issue

Tags: windows, jakarta-ee, windows-server-2003, tomcat7

We have a web application deployed on windows machine(64-bit) using tomcat (7.0.19) ,sometimes tomcat gets shut-down automatically (on production server)  and someone have to restart it manually , is there is any way to restart the tomcat server automatically (any plugin , open source software)??

Its a Java web app hosted on windows server 2003 , using tomcat 7..

any help would be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can have tomcat running as a service. Check out [the tomcat documentation on how to achieve this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html)